# What is the value of $\lim_{h\to 0}\dfrac{\sin\frac1h}{\frac1h}$

Tags: calculus, limits

$$\lim_{h\to 0}\dfrac{\sin\frac1h}{\frac1h}$$

Is the answer equal to $1$ or $0$?

Comment: Im thinking of the standard fact lim (sinx /x)=1 but the answer given in the solution show lim hsin(1/h)=0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put $t = \frac{1}{h} $. Hence,

$$ \lim_{h \to t } \frac{ \sin ( 1/h) }{(1/h)} = \lim_{t \to \infty} \frac{\sin t }{ t} $$

Not, since

$$ \frac{-1}{t} \leq \frac{ \sin t }{t} \leq \frac{1}{t} $$

An application of the squeeze trick, you obtain that

$$ \frac{ \sin t }{t} \to 0 $$

Comment: thanks so much understand already!?do you mind vote me thx!

Answer (score 2):

The limit is equivalent to $\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{\sin x}{x}$, which is $0$ since the numerator is bounded while the denominator is not.

Answer (score 1):

We  have $\lim_{h\to0}h\sin\dfrac1h$

Now for real $h,\left|\sin\dfrac1h\right|\le1$

So, the limit should $0\cdot$(a finite number)$=?$

Answer (score 1):

We have
$$\lim_{h\to0}{\dfrac{\sin\dfrac1h}{\dfrac1h}}=\lim_{h\to0}{h\sin\dfrac1h}$$
Now you can see that $\dfrac1h$ is a real number, so $-1\le\sin\dfrac1h\le1$. Also, $0$ multiplied by any number in interval $[-1,1]$ must be $0$, so solution is $0$.